# Grunt sass not outputting any css

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

This is my first time using Grunt and I'm confused why it's not outputting any css from my sass file.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'assets/css/style.css': 'assets/sass/_styles.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    }); 

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
};
```

When I run `grunt` in the terminal I receive a success message

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done, without errors.
```

But when I look in my style.css file, nothing is there.

I'm not sure if this is necessary, but this is my sass file

**_styles.scss**

```
$font-stack: Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
    font: 100% $font-stack;
    color: $primary-color;
}
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: why is it `_styles` instead of `styles`? might be erroring because it thinks this is a mixin.

Comment: Oh, thats just the way it was done on the tutorial I was following, http://christoph-rumpel.com/2014/01/how-to-laravel-series-two-ways-of-implementing-grunt-to-laravel/ Let me change it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Awesome, you were correct. If you put that in an answer, i'll accept. Otherwise i'll just delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `_styles.sass` to `styles.sass`, it's ignoring it because it thinks this is a mixin.